# Did I just get rid of my Hearthstone quests?

Tags: hearthstone

Two of my hearthstone quests had refresh circle-arrows or something on the upper right hand corner.  I clicked on them and new quests took their place.  I can't see the old quests now and I wanted to play them.  Did I just get rid of my hearthstone quests and is there any way to get them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get back your previous quest, but you should still have the same *number* of quests.

The button in the top right corner corner is a “reroll” button which **replaces that one quest with a new randomly-chosen quest.** You can only use it once per day.

The main use for the reroll button is if

- You don't want to attempt a quest (for example, it has a class you don't want to play).
- You'd like to take a chance on getting a quest with a higher gold reward. (This may be obsolete with [the November 2019 patch](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Patch_15.6.0.35747) which changes the quest list and reroll behavior; I'm not sure.)

Comment: If I hadn’t pressed the reroll button would I have gotten to complete more quests than the three I ended up with?

Comment: @WalrustheCat No. The only way the number of quests goes down is by completing them, and 3 is the limit you can have active.

Comment: Another way to look at it is: the re-roll button gives you another objective with a possibility of a different reward amount. You can't get more or less quests, you can only change the requirements for completion.